# LVM + add another new disk in order to extend current sdb disk size

Tags: centos, rhel, lvm, vmware, disk

we have linux OS with OS - sda and another disk for data

```
 df
Filesystem               1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg55-lvm_root  41932800 19731580  22201220  48% /
devtmpfs                  16372376        0  16372376   0% /dev
tmpfs                     16387592      108  16387484   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                     16387592  1741416  14646176  11% /run
tmpfs                     16387592        0  16387592   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg55-lvm_var  105756672 54652856  51103816  52% /var
/dev/sdb                  72117368 72100984         0 100% /data
/dev/sda1                   508588   160024    348564  32% /boot

  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda2  vg55 lvm2 a--  149.51g 92.00m
#
```

the problem is that /data is full , and we want to add another new disk from the VMcenter in order to extend the sdb disk to 200G

please advice how to perfrom the steps

Comment: Well, you can't extend the size of sdb by adding another disk because that other disk would become sdX. But if sdb is really a virtual disk, you can increase its size with your virtualization tools and then within the OS extend the partition and filesystem, adding the additional space to /data. I'm not sure how this is related to LVM given that /data is not an LVM logical volume, but rather a disk. Clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: what are the LVM commands for increase sdb ?

Comment: Yael, sdb is not an LVM logical volume, so the LVM commands do not apply. If sdb is actually a virtual disk (I can't tell from your post) you can increase its size with VMware. See https://pubs.vmware.com/fusion-5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.fusion.help.doc%2FGUID-2CE88716-DB0B-4612-AEFE-726E737E347B.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `/data` is not managed with LVM so you might add space so `/dev/sdb` via vCenter and then grow the file system in CentOs

```
xfs_growfs /dev/sdb
```

**LVM**

If you want to have LVM for `/data`, that will be a bit longer.

Add the disk to VMware, make it show in CentOS :

List host bus numbers :

```
ls /sys/class/scsi_host/
```

For each host bus, scan the bus (where [hostX] is the name you get from the previous command):

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/[hostX]/scan
```

Check the names of your SCSI devices

```
ls /sys/class/scsi_device/
```

Rescan the SCSI buses (name are in form X:X:X:X)

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_device/X\:X\:X\:X/device/rescan
```

Then you can `fdisk -l` to see your disk

First, you need to create a new Physical Volume with the new disk.

I assume that the disk will be sdc.

```
pvcreate /dev/sdc
```

Then you can create a new VG or use the existing one :

I assume you'll use the existing one :

`vgextend vg55 /dev/sdc`

You need to create a Logical Volume to use now

```
lvcreate -L200G -n lvm_data vg55
```

You now need to create a filesystem on this volume

```
mkfs.xfs /dev/mapper/vg55-lvm_data
```

You now have a 200GB disk that can be mounted. You might mount `lvm_data` somewhere, copy `/data` to the new volume, unmount `/data` and the `lvm_data`, and `mount /dev/mapper/vg55-lvm_data /data`.

**To add `/dev/sdb` to the LVM (if needed).**

Once you have your date moved elsewhere :

```
pvcreate /dev/sdb
```

Confirm you want to wipe the filesystem on `/dev/sdb` with `y`

Add /dev/sdb to the existing VG

```
vgextend vg55 /dev/sdb
```

Then you can allocate that space to the lv you want with

```
lvextend -L68G /dev/vg55/data
```